# How can we set selected option in select_tag with option_for_select in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select_tag in ruby on rails. The syntax for this is,

```
<%= select_tag "iso_region", options_for_select(@all_regions.collect {|p| [ "#{p['cc']}-#{p['lr']}", p['cc'] ] }), class: "form-control selectpicker reg_name", :data => {:'live-search' => 'true'} %>
```

Sample Options generated is like this,

```
<option value="ET">ET-Africa</option>
<option value="NG">NG-Africa</option>
<option value="PG">PG-Pacific</option>
<option value="IT">IT-Europe</option>
```

And I want IT-Europe to be selected in the dropdown.
How can I do that with my select_tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
options_for_select(@all_regions.collect {|p| [ "#{p['cc']}-#{p['lr']}", p['cc'] ] }, "IT"),
```

The last arg you pass to `options_for_select` is the value to be marked selected when it's rendered.